# Argo Rollouts dashboard not opening and command throws error invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: amazon-eks, argo, argo-rollouts

I have installed helm using

helm repo add argo https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
helm install my-release argo/argo-rollouts --set dashboard.enabled=true

then to check we use :
kubectl port-forward service/argo-rollouts-dashboard 31000:3100

I try to curl localhost:31000 and get [Found](/rollouts/). As the output.

But when i run:
kubectl argo rollouts dashboard , it throws error panic: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Please guide me in how to get Argo rollout dashboard running, i tried using an ALB to the service, but noo code is reflected there and health checks fail

I have installed helm using

helm repo add argo https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
helm install my-release argo/argo-rollouts --set dashboard.enabled=true

then to check we use :
kubectl port-forward service/argo-rollouts-dashboard 31000:3100

I try to curl localhost:31000 and get [Found](/rollouts/). As the output.

But when i run:
kubectl argo rollouts dashboard , it throws error panic: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Comment: Sounds like an authentication issue. I'd check your kubeconfig. You might be using the wrong API version.